Attachments in Pop Ups using Arcade
I am trying to write an expression:  if there is an attachment then display it.  I have this so far:
if(Count(Attachments($feature)) > 0)
{ return Attachments($feature)}

But it is returning this:
[object Object]

What am I missing?

Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

ArcGIS returns an array of attachments in Arcade, not just a single attachment.  So you need to loop through the array to pull out individual attachments, and likely have to structure some HTML as well

Have you researched this blog?

Is there a particular reason you aren't just using the Attachments pop-up group that is packaged with Map Viewer?
